# QAbstractItemModel Decoration Tooltip

Tags: qt, tooltip, qabstractitemmodel

I am trying to display a tooltip for a QAbstractItem but only when I hover over the decoration.

If I set the Qt::ToolTipRole then I get the tooltip if I hover over the entire item.

The call to model::data(..) only takes and index and role so I cant specify the area for the tool tip to be valid within.

Has anyone managed to do something like this before?

I have a delegate set up for the model too and thought I could use the editor event but that doesn't catch the QEvent::Tooltip ?

Perhaps just an eventfilter applied to the delegate or view could help?

Answer (score 2):

I would do it in the following way using an event filter installed on the target items view:

```
class Filter : public QObject
{
protected:
  bool eventFilter(QObject * watched, QEvent * event) override
  {
    if (auto view = qobject_cast<QAbstractItemView *>(watched)) {
      if (event->type() == QEvent::ToolTip) {
        auto helpEvent = static_cast<QHelpEvent *>(event);
        auto pos = view->viewport()->mapFrom(view, helpEvent->pos());
        auto index = view->indexAt(pos);

        // Assuming that the decoration size is 16x16
        auto rect = QRect(view->visualRect(index).topLeft(), QSize(16, 16));
        if (rect.contains(pos)) {
          QToolTip::showText(helpEvent->globalPos(), "This is a tooltip");
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
};
```

Installing this filter on a view:

```
QTreeWidget tw;
auto item = new QTreeWidgetItem(&tw, QStringList() << "Test");
item->setIcon(0, QIcon("icon.png"));

Filter filter;
tw.installEventFilter(&filter);
```

It handles all tool tip event, checks whether an event occurs on the decoration and, if yes, shows a tool tip with text.

Comment: Thanks vahancho, that's great. I'll give this a try! :)

Comment: Thanks again @vahancho. Unfortunately this didn't do the trick for me. I am using QTitanribbon and it seems to override the tooltips being displayed. back to the drawing board...

Comment: Your answer resolved my problem in Dec. 2022, although the coordinate mapping was a bit different in my case.